# mod 11 check digit with regex

Tags: regex, check-digit

Is it possible to create a mod 11 check digit routine with a regex statement?

THe nubmer is a 10 digit number,

Step 1:
A = (2nd number * 2) + (3rd number * 4) + (4th number * 8) + (5th number * 5) + (6th number * 10) + (7th number * 9) + (8th number * 7) + (9th number * 3))

Step 2:
B = A / 11 (ignor remainder)

Step 3:
C = B * 11

Step 4:
D = A - C

Step 5:
11 - D must = the 10th digit

Comment: Why use a regex when it's so straightforward without one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - fundamentally you're wanting to do maths here, and that doesn't really fit with regular expressions which are just about patterns.

I mean, *theoretically* it's certainly possible - you could list all valid numbers, and combine them into one enormous regex. However, it's not *practically* feasible.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say. Regex isn't a turing-complete language; math is one of the things it cannot do.

Answer (score 5):

Use regex as a finite state machine.  http://quaxio.com/triple/

Comment: Whoa... I really like this. While it's true that regex isn't well-suited to mathematical equations... the fact that it may be possible really is interesting to me.

Answer (score 0):

Regex does pattern matching, not really parsing.  You need to parse the number to get the digits.  I would suggest using the regex to ensure it is a 10 digit number and then ToString() it and chop it up.